# CollectionView.ReloadItemsForIndexPaths crash swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

Here is the code where it is crashes

```
 for var i=0;i<Data.NearByList.count;i++ {

            if let collectionView = collview {
                collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forItem: i, inSection: 0)])
            }

        }
```

i want to reload collectionView Data in viewdidApear because of some images appears not correctly
but always get this error

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSStackBlock__ _setNeedsFocusItemOverlayUpdate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x45426c'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2799386b 0x39092dff 0x27999035 0x27996c8f 0x278c62b8 0x2c2387d3 0x2c238379 0x2bb09dc3 0x2c241e7b 0x2bc82b45 0x2c2435fd 0x2bab3abd 0x2c242e25 0x2c2413fd 0x2bc7ea1d 0x1efe9c 0x2029e4 0x28694b8b 0x27947ffd 0x27947a0b 0x279477e1 0x2799bac3 0x278a904b 0x28692317 0x28696e4b 0x1fe0ec 0x117a6c 0xfe684 0x117bfc 0x27218a25 0x28750a05 0x286b24af 0x286a48bf 0x28752cc5 0x14bbdab 0x14c0829 0x27956595 0x27954a8f 0x278a71e9 0x278a6fdd 0x30b4baf9 0x2bb0c18d 0x1f51a8 0x397bd873)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`

Can someone found the solution for this

Comment: why do not just call collectionView.reloadData() ? Why is this iteration needed?

Comment: it's reload some of cells and some of images still appears not correctly

Comment: than your datasource is not refreshed i think. You should take care of that, instead of hacking the collectionView,

Comment: i want to have circle images in cells but some of them appears like "diamond"

Comment: I have all images in my datasource and most of them appears like circle

Comment: Than you should double check, based on what logic you are associating different images to your cells. I think the above code will be no help, and refreshing collection view cells, you should use collectionView.reloadData(), instead of the above pasted iteration.

Comment: Ok,can you explain why this doesn't woks,what selector i send to instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not sending this selector directly to the instance, but collectionview is sending it because it wants to update the cell.

First of all, make sure indexPath exists and since you are reloading lots of cells, you can create an Array - containing indexPaths and then reload all at once, you can also wrap reload-call into performBatchUpdates call, something like this.

```
var indexPathsToReload = [NSIndexPath]()
for var i in 0..<Data.NearByList.count {
    indexPathsToReload.append(NSIndexPath(forItem: i, inSection: 0))
}
```

then you can simply reload all at once

```
collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths(indexPathsToReload)
```

Or in batch updates ( you can include other updates too )

```
collectionView.performBatchUpdates({ () -> Void in
    collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths(indexPathsToReload)
    // Any additional change
    }) { (_) -> Void in
        print("Finished")
}
```

Comment: Hey its doesn't work  on device and I can't understand why.Still gives me this error

Comment: make sure you are reloading it at once and you are doing it from Main Thread, also , make sure Cells are properly set up

Comment: I reloading it once and in Main Thread
  var indexPathsToReload = [NSIndexPath]()
        
        for var i in 0..<13{
            indexPathsToReload.append(NSIndexPath(forItem: i, inSection: 0))
        }
        let qualityOfServiceClass = dispatch_get_main_queue()
        let backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue()
        dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, {
         self.collview.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths(indexPathsToReload)
        })
How can i check if cells are set up? i run it in timer function where i can run it?